# Exception when validating a PDF file with veraPDF

Tags: validation, pdf

I used the code from verapdf here
http://docs.verapdf.org/develop/
to validate a pdf file. I chose the greenfield parser.

But when I ran the code, I got the Exception as follows.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.verapdf.gf.model.impl.cos.GFCosDocument.getcontainsEmbeddedFiles()Ljava/lang/Boolean;

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:161)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:247)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:119)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10._c0(unnamed script:0)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10.call(unnamed script)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10.call(unnamed script)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c10.exec(unnamed script)
at org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.JavaScriptEvaluator.getTestEvalResult(JavaScriptEvaluator.java:117)
at org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.BaseValidator.checkObjWithRule(BaseValidator.java:292)
at org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.BaseValidator.firstProcessObjectWithRule(BaseValidator.java:288)
at org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.BaseValidator.checkAllRules(BaseValidator.java:261)
at org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.BaseValidator.checkNext(BaseValidator.java:170)
at org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.BaseValidator.validate(BaseValidator.java:123)
at org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.BaseValidator.validate(BaseValidator.java:94)
```

Comment: As Boris writes in his answer, the pdf in question is needed for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Such exceptions can be a result of the invalid syntax of the PDF file you are trying to validate. It is very difficult to provide more detailed response without seeing your document.

You can submit this issue at https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-library and attach your document to it.